# Method to count all rows in my database crashes my app

Tags: java, android, exception, android-sqlite, illegalstateexception

I am trying to count all rows in my app. As soon as I call the following method the app crashes:

```
public int getDBPlacesCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DB_VERLADESTELLEN_Eintrag;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
```

The exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an
>   already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT  * FROM orte

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to get the cursor count, but the line above you close the connection to the database. You should get the count first, then close the connection, something like:

```
public int getDBPlacesCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DB_VERLADESTELLEN_Eintrag;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return count
    }
```

Comment: @Glave My pleasure! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

You have tried to `read` from the cursor which is already `closed`, which is wrong.

You need to change your code as shown below:

```
public int getDBPlacesCount() {
    try {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DB_VERLADESTELLEN_Eintrag;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        long count = cursor.getCount();

        // return count
        return count;
     } catch(SQLException exe) {
        //log exceptions
     } finally {
       if(cursor != null) {
          //always close the cursor in finally and make it null
          cursor.close();
          cursor = null;
       }
     }
}
```

Also, ensure that you are CLOSING the cursor in the `finally` block to avoid the leakage.